# Shell Programming using sed to delete a line from txt file

Tags: scripts, grep, sed

I want to remove a line from a .txt file using the grep and sed functions but the output I get does not alter any of my info in the text file. Any suggestions on how to get the desired output? Thank you.

- Both title and year are declared as an array;
- The format of info in the .txt file is 
  (title) : (year) : (views) : (rating)

---

```
function remove_movie
{
    echo "Please Key in Title of movie"
    read title 
    echo "Please Key in the Year of movie"
    read year 
    echo ""
    grep ".*$title.*$year" movieDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]
    then
        sed  -i '/$title/d' movieDB.txt
        echo $movieDB "  ' $title 'movie deleted successfully "
    else
        echo "The movie $title does not exist."
    fi
}
```

Comment: Single quotes around `'/$title/d'` prevent expansion of the variable: your `sed` command is trying to delete lines containing the literal string `$title`. Why are you declaring `title` and `year` as arrays?

Comment: Why do you claim "`$movieDB "  ' $title 'movie deleted successfully "`" when you have not checked the exit status (`$?`) of `sed`.

Comment: i declared title and year as an array to store the information in the array then use it to form a line in the .txt file.

Comment: it is a message i would like to display on the terminal after the sed process has been completed. So what would i have to do to check exit status before i display a success message?

Answer (score 2):

All I did was to change the single quotes to double quotes and the function I need worked well. Thank You [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for pointing that out. For the exit status of `sed` pointed out by [@waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) will work on it too so that I can get the program as bug free as possible.

Once again thank you [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) and [@waltinator](https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator) :)

```
function remove_movie
{
    echo "Please Key in Title of movie"
    read title 
    echo "Please Key in the Year of movie"
    read year 
    echo ""
    grep ".*$title.*$year" movieDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]
    then
        sed  -i "/$title/d" movieDB.txt
        echo $movieDB "  ' $title 'movie deleted successfully "
    else
        echo "The movie $title does not exist."
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some additional things:

```
   1  function remove_movie
   2  {
   3      echo "Please Key in Title of movie"
   4      read title 
   5      echo "Please Key in the Year of movie"
   6      read year 
   7      echo ""
   8      grep ".*$title.*$year" movieDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 
   9      if [ "$?" = "0" ]
  10      then
  11          sed  -i '/$title/d' movieDB.txt
                      ^––SC2016 Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
  12          echo $movieDB "  ' $title 'movie deleted successfully "
                   ^––SC2154 movieDB is referenced but not assigned.
                   ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
  13      else
  14          echo "The movie $title does not exist."
  15      fi
  16  }
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.shellcheck.net/)</sub>